# How much does respeccing cost?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I gather that I can pay to respec my abilities, but does the cost go up permanently once I use it, or can I respec periodically for a low price?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Patch 1.5, subscribers can respec for free and cost is reduced for Preferred players.  The numbers below should still apply for Free players.  See "Respecialization" at http://www.swtor.com/free/features

The following information has been gleaned from the links attached:

- Respec costs reset every week in-game for all characters.
- The first resec is free, with each subsequent respec for the week increasing in price.
- The relative cost of each respec does seem to be linked to your characters level, with higher characters costing more.
- The respec cost caps at 100,000 in game currency, regardless of your level.

Relevant links:

- http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=57064
- http://justforgamer.blogspot.com/2011/12/swtor-respec-time.html
- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/951199-star-wars-the-old-republic/61471715 ( this may be a bug )
- http://r2-db.com/questions/549/respec-cost-scaling
- http://www.gamezone.com/editorials/respec-swtor-guide

Give it a while and there will probably be a respec calculator available, probably as an addon to the many already avalable skills calculators such as [this one at tor-head.](http://www.torhead.com/skill-calc)

Here are some quoted coss I have found:

Level 29 char (no spec given):

- 1st time – 0 credits
- 2nd time – 400 Credits
- 3rd time – 2675 credits
- 4th time – 8000 credits

Level 25 char (no class given)

- 1st = 0
- 2nd = 300
- 3rd = 1950
- 4th = 5850
- 5th = 12750

No level given:

- 1st time: free
- 2nd: 1800 cred
- 3rd: 8300
- 4th: 25000
- 5th: 50000

No level given:

- 1st. free
- 2nd. 300
- 3rd. 2k
- 4th. 10k

I hope this helps :)

P.S. If you have came to this thread looking for a more detailed answer, I am currently asking for more detailed information to work with on the [SWTOR forum](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=975825#post975825), so please stop by and help.

Comment: I would really like to see the costs for a level 50.